# CMake add_executable spontaneously generating a library

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, cmake

I'm trying to use CMake to compile a couple of simple test programs, on Windows, for Postgres and MySQL respectively. The Postgres one works as expected, but the MySQL one works not quite as expected; specifically, it generates a library alongside the executable, even though I specified an executable, not a library. Why is it doing this?

This is my CMakeLists.txt. The only visible difference is that CMake already understands how to find the necessary files for Postgres, whereas I needed to write some instructions to find them for MySQL; is that somehow influencing the end result?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(olivine)

find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)

add_executable(test-postgres test-postgres.cpp)
target_include_directories(test-postgres PRIVATE ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(test-postgres PRIVATE ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES})

if(WIN32)
    find_path(MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR
        NAMES "mysql.h"
        PATHS
            "$ENV{PROGRAMFILES}/MySQL/*/include"
            "$ENV{SYSTEMDRIVE}/MySQL/*/include")
    find_library(MYSQL_LIBRARY
        NAMES "mysqlclient"
        PATHS
            "$ENV{PROGRAMFILES}/MySQL/*/lib"
            "$ENV{SYSTEMDRIVE}/MySQL/*/lib")
endif()

add_executable(test-mysql test-mysql.cpp)
target_include_directories(test-mysql PRIVATE ${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(test-mysql PRIVATE ${MYSQL_LIBRARY})
```

And this is the current output. (The DLLs turned out to be needed to run test-postgres.exe, so I copied them into the directory myself.)

```
 Directory of C:\olivine\build\Debug

06/12/2023  07:14 PM    <DIR>          .
06/12/2023  07:13 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/07/2023  04:20 AM         4,561,920 libcrypto-3-x64.dll
06/07/2023  04:20 AM           775,168 libssl-3-x64.dll
06/12/2023  07:14 PM         8,736,768 test-mysql.exe
06/12/2023  07:14 PM               707 test-mysql.exp
06/12/2023  07:14 PM             1,774 test-mysql.lib
06/12/2023  07:14 PM        11,554,816 test-mysql.pdb
06/12/2023  06:31 PM            75,264 test-postgres.exe
06/12/2023  06:31 PM         1,445,888 test-postgres.pdb
```

Comment: The library is generated first, which is an intermediate step, and then the exe is generated. I do not see a problem as that is the way cmake generates build files on Windows. One benefit of generating the .lib is to remove unreferenced code which results in a smaller exe size.

Comment: Note, that PATHS parameter doesn't accept *globbing expression* (`$ENV{PROGRAMFILES}/MySQL/*/include`). Effectively, the only commands in CMake which accepts globbing expression are `file(GLOB)` and `file(GLOB_RECURSE)`.

Comment: @JohnHanley It's not so much that it's a problem – it does work, after all – as that I'm trying to understand what's going on, because if I don't understand how the tool works, I could trip up in some unexpected way in the future. In particular, if that's just how it generates build files on Windows, why did it *not* do the same thing for the other program that seems to be defined in pretty much the same way?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Oh? That is interesting to know, but then why does it appear to work here?

Comment: "why does it appear to work here?" - Are you sure they actually work? Your could e.g. just remove all that `PATHS` parameters and try to reconfigure the project (with empty build directory).

Comment: I cannot answer why Microsoft chose to create a lib before the final link. Perhaps someone knows the history. I have written a linker for Visual Studio and I used that technique to reduce program size by dropping dead code. My guess is that Microsoft chose to not delete the lib created by the intermediate step before creating the final exe.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I've tested the programs, and they work.